# Configuring the Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.0.0 with API Manager 1.9.0

Tags: database, wso2, integration, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Hello I m trying to configure Identity Server and API manager . 
 using the official

[Tutorial here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.0)

Here it is mentioned that **"Make the following change in the IS_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml  file.  Change the    under the    section so that it points to the API Manager server".** 
but Their is no api-Manager.xml exist in above mentioned directory or in any other of identity Server. 

Still i made changes in api-manager.xml of Wso2 API Manager. 
 

But running The following Command to start the server : **PRODUCT_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh -Dsetup** 


i m getting Windows Popup Stating , Windows can't open the file Wso2server.sh to open this file choose the program below .

Please correct me where i m doing wrong.

Comment: With a fresh new Download i got APi-manager.xml in IS manager .
 but still stucking with wso2server.sh -Dsetup command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on windows try running wso2server.bat instead of wso2server.sh.

Joe

Comment: It solved the question you asked if it has other issues that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to copy the api-manager.xml across from the API Manager VM to the Identity Server. the changes need to be made to api-manager.xml in both servers.

Also when starting the server in unix, make sure you have environment variables set, JAVA_HOME and CARBON_HOME.